# Update query PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Can anybody help me understand why this update query isn't updating the fields in my database? I have this in my php page to retrieve the current values from the database:

```
<?php

  $query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM blogEntry WHERE username = 'bobjones' ORDER BY id DESC");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($query)) 
  {
      $id = $row['id']; 
      $username = $row['username'];
      $title = $row['title'];
      $date = $row['date'];
      $category = $row['category'];
      $content = $row['content'];


    ?>
```

Here i my HTML Form:

```
<form method="post" action="editblogscript.php">
ID: <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /><br />
Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>" /><br />
Title: <input type="text" name="udtitle" value="<?php echo $title; ?>"/><br />
Date: <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>"/><br />
Message: <textarea name = "udcontent" cols="45" rows="5"><?php echo $content; ?></textarea><br />
<input type= "submit" name = "edit" value="Edit!">
</form>
```

and here is my 'editblogscript':

```
<?php

mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("blogass");

if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $udtitle = $_POST['udtitle'];
    $udcontent = $_POST['udcontent'];


    mysql_query("UPDATE blogEntry SET content = $udcontent, title = $udtitle WHERE id = $id");
}

header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;





?>
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to have single quotes around any VARCHAR content in your queries. So your update query should be:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE blogEntry SET content = '$udcontent', title = '$udtitle' WHERE id = $id");
```

Also, it is bad form to update your database directly with the content from a POST. You should sanitize your incoming data with the mysql_real_escape_string function.

Comment: around any string I believe. say, there are no varchar nor fields at all in the query `SELECT 'Hello World';` but quotes still required.

Comment: This is out of date.

Comment: Yes, dear modern users, do not use this deprecated and insecure query.  You should use `mysqli` or `pdo` with prepared statements and placeholders to make the query secure.  Never blindly write user-submitted data directly into your query.

Comment: Yes, for sure this is not the right way to execute a mysql query in php. It answers the original question, but is out of date.

Answer (score 6):

Need to add quote for that need to use dot operator:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE blogEntry SET content = '".$udcontent."', title = '".$udtitle."' WHERE id = '".$id."'");
```

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing what the actual error you are getting is I would guess it is missing quotes. try the following:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE blogEntry SET content = '$udcontent', title = '$udtitle' WHERE id = '$id'")
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Here i updated two variables and present date and time

$id    = "1";
$title = "phpmyadmin";

```
 $sql=  mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET id ='".$id."', title = '".$title."',now() WHERE id = '".$id."' ");
```

now() function update current date and time.

```
note: For update query we have define the particular id otherwise it update whole table defaulty
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should define "doesn't work".
Second, I assume that your table field 'content' is varchar/text, so you need to enclose it in quotes. `content = '{$content}'`
And last but not least: use `echo mysql_error()` directly after a query to debug.

Comment: use `mysql_error()` to find any error with database.. By this way you can solve your issues

Comment: echoing doesn't seem convenient method.  what if an error occurred while you're away?

Comment: I'd suggest to use trigger_error(). it will not only follow site-wide error-reporting rules (log or display) but also provide both filename and line number, which info can be priceless in case of logging errors

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in sql query, It will work fine.

```
$sql="UPDATE create_test set url= '$_POST[url]' WHERE test_name='$test_name';";
```

If you have to update multiple columns,
Use like this,

```
$sql="UPDATE create_test set `url`= '$_POST[url]',`platform`='$_POST[platform]' WHERE test_name='$test_name';";
```

Answer (score -1):

you must write single quotes then double quotes then dot before name of field and after like that

```
mysql_query("UPDATE blogEntry SET content ='".$udcontent."', title = '".$udtitle."' WHERE id = '".$id."' ");
```