# Updating rows in mysql with a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

Just started learning php and this is my first project:
sort list items and save that new order to database. But I'm really stuck on how to save the order with the new order numbers.

I have an array like this:
[order numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rySm.png)

and I want to loop through this and update the *ordernumber* column in my table.

so far I have this set up:

```
foreach ($a as $key => $neworder) {
    $sql = "UPDATE todoitem SET ordernumber = '$key' WHERE Id = '$neworder'";
}
```

But when I sort the list items, I get this:
[todoitem table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KSEL.png)

Only the last row gets updated and the order number is 3? I don't understand where the 3 come from.

I've been scratching my head at this for a few days and I'm so stuck...

Comment: The above statement only shows the query - where is actually **executed** ? Perhaps outside the loop, this would explain why only the *last* item got updated. Also, please update your question and show the text rather than providing images.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893551/update-query-php-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
foreach ($a as $key => $neworder) {
```

is looping from 0-3 (since there are 4 keys in your array by those numbers).

This:

```
$sql = "UPDATE todoitem SET ordernumber = '$key' WHERE Id = '$neworder'";
```

Is setting the `$sql` variable to a string, built by the `$key` and `$neworder` values.

Now, the code never actually does anything with that query inside that loop.  It just over-writes it each time.  So the *last* iteration of the loop will be the value of `$sql` after the loop.  (Presumably *that's* where you're actually using it in some way.)

If my assumption is correct and you are executing the query *after* the loop, then the code is semantically doing the following:

- Set the query to use 0.
- Set the query to use 1.
- Set the query to use 2.
- Set the query to use 3.
- Execute the query.

It's only executed once.  Maybe you meant to execute the query inside of the loop?

Comment: Thanks! I was dumb and didn't put the execution code inside the loop... Much more to learn!

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your `$sql` variable in the loop. You should also execute it inside the loop. This way only the last `$sql` gets executed.

As for the line with id 4 having ordernumber 3, you might want to change your sql parameters - switch `$key` with `$neworder`. That is

```
"UPDATE todoitem SET ordernumber = '$neworder' WHERE Id = '$key'";
```