# how to do update query statement in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Please Correct me here, i am trying to update or insert values in existing row in my database, but not able to this, all the variables is working but its not getting into database also checked in phpmyadmin sql query but it was not working there also, there it shows success but not a single data getting into mysql columns..

```
include("connect.php");

$sql = "UPDATE tblapps SET applsex='$applsex', placbrth='$placbrth', countrybrth='$countrybrth', religionxx='$religionxx', visualmark='$visualmark', edu_id='$edu_id', nationality_by='$nationality_by', prev_nationality='$prev_nationality', issueplace='$issueplace', expirydate='$expirydate', othpassport='$otherpassport', oth_passportno='$oth_pass_no', oth_pptissueplc='$oth_ppt_issue_place', oth_pptissuentl='$oth_ppt_nationality', country_issue='$country_issue', previssuedate='$previssuedate' WHERE app_id=$appid";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records were updated successfully.";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

?>
```

this is the error, I am getting.

```
ERROR: Could not able to execute UPDATE tblapps SET applsex='', placbrth='delhi', countrybrth='United States', religionxx='CHRISTIAN', visualmark='', edu_id='GRADUATE', nationality_by='By Birth', prev_nationality='', issueplace='delhi', expirydate='2018-11-01', othpassport='on', oth_passportno='9876546789', oth_pptissueplc='delhi', oth_pptissuentl='United States', country_issue='', previssuedate='2018-01-02' WHERE app_id='1515130357782247085'. Unknown column 'othpassport' in 'field list'
```

Comment: What error you get

Comment: May be it's question duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893551/update-query-php-mysql

Comment: can you post query that you tried on phpmyadmin?

Comment: @maddy23285  this is the error, i am getting.

Comment: @TarangP - this is the error, i am getting.

Comment: You sure the table you're trying to update contains `othpassport` and is spelled correctly in your sql statement?

Comment: @YusufHassan : yes now its working. there were some field missspelled..

Comment: I see no insert here

Answer (score 2):

> Unknown column 'othpassport' in 'field list'

This meant to say that othpassport coloumn is not available in your database table.
Kindly check table or rename it.

*i hope it helps*.

Answer (score 1):

> You  are getting error : Unknown column 'othpassport' in 'field list'

This meant to say that `othpassport` coloumn is not available in your database table or you typed it wrong. And according to your coding style I think the column name may be `otherpassport` . Hope you find it helpful , Thanks!!

Comment: @Gaurav Singh edited that question after I posted my answer

Comment: At that time how would anyone know what is the error he getting @TarangP

Comment: Also I dont have that much point to ask query in comment @TarangP